# Bash script file size

Tags: linux, bash

I have got script like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/gamesimport/
ls -t games*.xml | tail -n+2 | xargs rm
mv games*.xml games_ok.xml
```

It's just deleting old games*.xml files, renaming the lastest games.xml file but I would like also to change name if games.xml file is larger then 1 MB. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s games_ok.xml) 
MAX=1048576
if [ $FILESIZE -ge $MAX ]; then
#do something else
fi
```

should work

Comment: No spaces in `MAX=1048576` otherwise `MAX: command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, use find:

```
find some/where -name games\*.xml -size +1M -exec mv {} {}.big \;
```